# Sorting Excel tables by localized alphabetical order

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, localization

The English Excel (improperly) sorts the following strings as follows:

```
SARKIN
ŞENER
SEZER
ŞİMŞEK
SÜRMELİ
```

However, these are all Turkish strings where S and Ş are strictly different letters and Ş comes after S. Therefore the proper Turkish sorting would be like this:

```
SARKIN
SEZER
SÜRMELİ
ŞENER
ŞİMŞEK
```

How does one make the English Excel sort localized strings properly, particularly the Turkish?

Comment: [Alphabetizing Foreign Language Lists in Excel - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/alphabetizing-foreign-language-lists-in-excel/2ab9f5b2-89ee-4ded-86f8-d2f9fe3c2c33) has some code for Romanian which you may be able to adapt.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you already have Turkish set at a system language and inside Excel's own language settings. Perhaps if you use the localised "SIRALA" function it might implement the proper Turkish alphabet sort order. You can use the Windows Language bar shortcuts to quickly toggle between system languages (left shift + ALT, or Windows Button + space). Hopefully Excel toggles its own language system at the same time.

As an alternative, create a helper column and sort according to this column:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A1),"Ç","Czzzzz"),"Ğ","Gzzzzz"),"İ","Izzzzz"),"Ö","Ozzzzz"),"Ş","Szzzzz"),"Ü","Uzzzzz")
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will work:

```
=LET(Range, A1:A5,  Sort, IFERROR(UNICHAR(SORT(TEXT(IFERROR(UNICODE(MID(Range,SEQUENCE(1,MAX(LEN(Range))),1)),0),"0000")))," "),

     TRIM(MID(TEXTJOIN("",FALSE,Sort),SEQUENCE(ROWS(Range),1,1,MAX(LEN(Range))),MAX(LEN(Range))))
     )
```

It's not something of the "elegant" kind, just takes after the problem and chunks its way through.

The point of putting the `Range` Name in the first line is more that it is placed at the absolute start of the formula, and so is visible and easily selected even by keyboard alone for editing to match one's exact range of the moment. That beats hunting for all occurrences throughout a long formula, or having to select the cell and one other to do a `Find and Replace` in. I like them all first mainly for this reason, but also because if I have more than two, I put "primary" Names in the first line (so I can edit them easily), then secondary ones in further lines. I also like to do them in hierarchy, so the second line uses things from the first, but not from itself as those go into the third line, and so on. It ensures I don't get ahead of myself and use a Name I haven't defined yet. (I also edited the formula shown above a little so it shows the indentation lining things up. If you copy and paste though, you'll need to add a couple spaces in the >first lines to restore their appearance in the Excel `Formula Bar`.

*(By the way, you can drag that `Formula Bar` bottom edge down so as many lines as you like are available in it. Need 13 lines to see the whole formula? Just drag it down so you have them.)*

In the `LET()`, the `Sort` Name does the following:

1. `MID()` breaks each word into strings of one character each. A "gotcha" point here is that if you use something other than "1" for the "ROWS" parameter in `SEQUENCE()`, things fail. You'd think "5" for this exact problem, but...
2. `UNICODE()` gets the Unicode character value for the number of characters in the longest word in the range.
3. `IFERROR()` converts errors (that occur when many words are less than the longest words number of characters) into zeros. Not blanks as you want them to succeed in the next step.
4. `TEXT()` converts these values to text, which is NOT required in and of itself, but is needed so that the values can be four characters long for the "alphabetization" step coming up. If the Unicode values could be longer, you'd add more digits to the text output for each value. You are going to sort each as a full text string, not a collection of numbers, so you need this. It is analogous to the technique of storing dates in `(yy)yymmdd` form so that they sort as text rather than using numerical values assigned to them like Excel does. Doing it this way, as a string of equal size chunks, allows for sorting by first letter, then second, and so on, as one would expect, without having to provide for a dynamic multitude of individual sorts as if each position in the words were a column.
5. `SORT()` sorts the strings.
6. `UNICHAR()` returns them to being letters. It will fail on blanks, so...
7. `IFERROR()` converts those errors to single spaces. They will all occur at the end and later on `TRIM()` will remove them. (`TRIM()` cannot be used in this "half" without words breaking into new words in unfortunate places.)

So now you have a nice array of single letters in word-sorted order.

Then the "working formula", i.e.:  second half of the formula (you can put it all together in a single, LONG, formula string, but it seemed natural to me to break it at this place), begins work:

1. `TEXTJOIN()` collects all the characters, including spaces, into a single string. Perhaps the new text/array functions Excel is impressing the press with will make this simpler in a year or two, but for now... Actually, this is a case where `CONCAT()` would serve nicely if desired as there is no delimiter being added herein so no extra one at the end, which is ordinarily the problem with it. This is a point in which you could probably write an elegant `INDEX()` that would give you seven-character-long (in this case) strings instead, but this is just chunking through so...
2. `MID()` breaks the string into seven character chunks using `SEQUENCE()` to generate how many rows (the `ROWS(Range)` part), the one output column you need (so not "seven" hoping to provide for the fact that the number of columns in the first half's array was seven:  you focus on output here and that is a single column. It uses the third and fourth parameters to start at character 1 and take pieces seven characters long... so the seven (`MAX(LEN(Range))`) DOES come into play, just not in both places in the function.
3. `TRIM()` then removes those extra spaces at the end that occur for most of these strings. The nicety here is that single spaces that occurred in any words (I know, word vs. words, but we all know many things we first think of as "word" (singular) are often two or more words (plural) or at least two or more sets of letters with spaces between them.) will be preserved. Languages I am familiar with (NOT Turkish, sadly for this point!) do not use multiple spaces between such words that make a single "word" so `TRIM()` should cause no problems IN a word presented to the formula.

And now you have a list properly sorted. "Properly" in computer terms as most sorting done by computer is actually this, the ordering by character "value" (or Unicode character value if one is lucky... so not in Excel...).

I do point out two potential issues:

1. If you have an operating system and/or Excel language version that works natively in Turkish, it could turn out that following Unicode values is not how it sorts Turkish. I don't know, so I cannot speak to that, or how one might trap and allow for such differences here. So this formula's output might not perfectly capture proper Turkish language sorting and might not be easily fixable to do so. But if Turkish language sorting does follow Unicode character values (and I believe it was usual for the folks placing characters in most Unicode language blocks to at least think in terms of sorting when doing so), then this will do that.

Clarification point on "Turkish language version of Excel":  I do NOT mean simply installing the Turkish language package in Excel. I tried that to see if it would work (or provide extra standard number/date formatting choices) but it did not. I suppose it now spellchecks Turkish words, if I ever need that (did not see a way to de-install it so I guess I'm keeping it) and maybe some other small things. Bigger if I tell it to be the default language, I'd think, but nothing of use to me. Which by the way, I did not, so actually, potentially, if I did do that, sorting Turkish words might immediately become no problem at all, but I strongly doubt it. I'm thinking it's more along the lines of error messages and menu items (oopsy... sorry... RIBBON items... that Ribbon isn't a menu system with many sub-menus, MS advertising said so for years and years) would be in Turkish.
2. The `TEXTJOIN()` command builds a string internal to the formula. Often such things have a length limit and the longest length limit for anything limited by length in a formula is about 32,767 characters, and often less, sometimes as few as a bit over 6,000. Not all internal arrays are internal strings though this one definitely is. Actually, it's a decided fact:  just experimented and `TEXTJOIN()` is happy building a 32,767 character-long string, but gives the `#CALC!` error when I add one more character.

So... if your list is not too long for it, the formula will work. The length used in this set of five was seven, so 4,681 (exactly, interestingly enough) words would be doable.

If reaching the 32,767 character limit, a helper column with just the `IFERROR(TEXT())` portion would let you sort perfectly, no matter how long a list and how many characters, at least up to the 4GB (minus hotel load) that Excel can operate with.

This would be a good moment to mention that the mention I made above of a more elegant solution probably being available using `INDEX()` instead of `TEXTJOIN()` is a perhaps useful thought. `TEXTJOIN()` makes the process create a string of the length "ROWS * MAX(LEN(individual words)), or 5*7 = 35 in this case, which can easily run up against the max string length in the internal workings of a formula. It would take less than 5,000 words with the longest only seven characters long. Just one 20 character word and you're down to 1,600-ish due to that string being created.

`INDEX()` would create an ARRAY OF STRINGS, not a single long string. Then the limit is available for each string it creates. You simply don't have a 32,767 character-long name in your data, so that problem goes away. In other things I've experimented on, I never ran into `INDEX()` failing to use any range, even very big ones. I have, run into other functions creating stunted arrays (ending in the middle of an element, not even truncating the array at the last full element) when reaching some limit or the other, and it's very possible `INDEX()` would do the same, just that I never exercised it in exactly this way. My uses would seem to be looking for particular rows (`INDEX/MATCH`-style), or small enough subsets to pass on to something else, that I never hit the limit. So even `INDEX()` might not handle a large set of names. Since I am ending now (it's getting hard to think anyone is still reading the answer at this point!), and not experimenting to use it here, I cannot speak past this to that but... it seems worthwhile if you find the above useful, but that it is too limited in the data sets it can sort all at once as you might commonly have data sets that exceed its limits.